# Firebase facebook popup returns null onAuth

Tags: android, popup, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

My firebase facebook popup login on ionic was working correctly but suddenly it stop working (well, i was modifiying the app but i didnt touch the service). The process still works on browser (when i use ionic serve) but not running on ionic app.

```
var auth = $fAuth(ref);
  // login with Facebook
  auth.$onAuth(function(authData){ // authData -> null
    console.log("Auth..", authData);  // Auth.. null  
    /* refresh user data on firebase and registering push */
  });
  auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook").catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Authentication failed:", error);
  });
```

When it was working, $onAuth cb function was recieving an object in authData variable with properties like uid and facebook.

when i run:

```
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook",function(){console.log(arguments)})
```

or:

```
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("twitter",function(){console.log(arguments)})
```

the callback function never fires.

I run the auth process on $ionicPlatform.ready event.
I already uninstalled and reinstalled the app, and cleaned app data.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it doesn't fire?

> A callback function that will be called when authentication has completed. On failure, the first argument will be an Error object indicating the failure, with a machine-readable code attribute. **On success, the first argument will be null and the second will be an object containing the fields uid (the unique user id), provider (string identifying the provider), auth (the auth. token payload), and expires (expiration time in seconds since the Unix epoch)** - and more, depending upon the provider used to authenticate.

You didn't put the arguments there.
I think it should work if you try it again.
Example code from firebase:

```
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
//                                          ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh is just for make it short, "arguments" is the array with all the arguments passed to the function when its called, i tried the code you suggest too and it doesnt fires :/

Comment: As i said, the callback of authWithOAuthPopuo doesnt even fires. I recieve the null in the callback of onAuth. ref.onAuth(function(data){ /* here data is null */});

Comment: the first parameter of the function is the error object. the **second** is the actual data. If the first parameter is null, it means that it was successful (/there is no error).
`ref.onAuth(function(error, data){ /* error will be null, data should be the auth-object */});`

Comment: Hmm, i tried and i recieve error -> null and data -> undefined. I checked firebase docs, onAuth callback only pass one parameter (here is the link: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html)

Comment: oh sorry, that's my bad i meant `authWithOAuthPopup`, not onAuth(). [here's the link](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html)

Comment: Ohh no prob, thanks for helping :). i already tried authWithOAuthPopup with parameters too but the cb function never is called.

Comment: could you provide a plunkr/jsfiddle/something like that? i think it would be easier to help.

Comment: The prob is that it still working on browser but not on the ionic platform( as an hybrid android app)